# How to assign extra attributes to Tween.js ( https://github.com/sole/tween.js/ )

Tags: javascript, animation, tween, tween.js

So I am working on tweening between two values, but do not know if they will be position or scale. Because of this I am creating a Tween which contains an if statement on the update loop/

```
if( params.type == 'position' ){

  initial = {
    x: params.object.position.x,    
    y: params.object.position.y,
    z: params.object.position.z
  }

  target = {
    x: params.target.x,
    y: params.target.y,
    z: params.target.z,
  }

}else if( params.type == 'scale' ){

  intial = {
    x: params.object.scale.x,    
    y: params.object.scale.y,
    z: params.object.scale.z
  }

  target = {
    x: params.target.x,
    y: params.target.y,
    z: params.target.z,
  }


}

var tween = new TWEEN.Tween( initial ).to( target , params.time * 1000 );
tween.easing( params.easing );


// Need to assign these for the update loop
tween.object    = params.object;
tween.type      = params.type;
tween.tweener   = this;
tween.initial   = initial;
tween.target    = target;
tween.callback  = params.callback;

tween.onUpdate(function( tween ){

  if( this.type == 'position' ){
    this.object.position.x = this.initial.x;
    this.object.position.y = this.initial.y;
    this.object.position.z = this.initial.z;
  }else if( this.type == 'scale' ){
    this.object.scale.x = this.initial.x;
    this.object.scale.y = this.initial.y;
    this.object.scale.z = this.initial.z;
  }

  if( this.initial.x == this.target.x ){

    var i = this.tweener.tweens.indexOf( this );
    this.tweener.tweens.splice( i , 1 );

    this.callback();

  }

});
```

The problem with this is that in the onUpdate loop,  the

```
this
```

refers to

```
tween.intial
```

instead of

```
tween
```

Is there any way to reference tween in this situation rather than what I am actually tweening?

Thank you in advance for your help!
Isaac

Comment: Just change `tween.onUpdate(function( tween ){` to `tween.onUpdate(function(){` and use everywhere `tween` instead of `this`. So change `if( this.type == 'position' ){` to `if( tween.type == 'position' ){` etc.

Comment: That would work, but I think that the tween will be overwritten later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a bind to the end( I'm very bad at javascript it turns out... )

tween.onUpdate(function( tween ){

if( this.type == 'position' ){
    this.object.position.x = this.initial.x;
    this.object.position.y = this.initial.y;
    this.object.position.z = this.initial.z;
  }else if( this.type == 'scale' ){
    this.object.scale.x = this.initial.x;
    this.object.scale.y = this.initial.y;
    this.object.scale.z = this.initial.z;
  }

if( this.initial.x == this.target.x ){

```
var i = this.tweener.tweens.indexOf( this );
this.tweener.tweens.splice( i , 1 );

this.callback();
```

}

}.bind( tween ));